# Как ввести пароль в bash через скрипт?

Tags: bash, ssh, shell

При подключении к серверу по SSH через скрипт есть надобность ввести пароль.

---

Получается так, что, при подключении к серверу он запрашивает пароль:

```
ssh server@192.168.1.101         //Выполняю команду
server@192.168.1.101's password: //Выводит консоль
```

Адреса постоянно меняются, пароли приходят извне.

---

Как через скрипт ввести пароль?

Comment: Мотив отсутствия возможности указать пароль при подключении ssh - не использовать пароли, использовать ключи. (конечно можно при желании и пароль в скрипте использовать, но я вам не скажу)

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, aдреса постоянно меняются, пароли приходят из вне. Мне нужно именно вписатт пароль.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Как через скрипт ввести пароль?

например, воспользоваться программой *sshpass* (в популярных дистрибутивах операционной системы *gnu/linux* входит в одноимённый пакет):

```
$ sshpass -p 'пароль' ssh пользователь@сервер
```

> aдреса постоянно меняются

в этом случае понадобится отключить проверку *known hosts*, добавив опции `-q -o 'UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null' -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no'` к вызвову программы *ssh*:

```
$ sshpass -p 'пароль' ssh -q -o 'UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null' -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' пользователь@сервер
```

Answer (score 2):

Лучше настроить систему [ключей](https://www.opennet.ru/base/sec/ssh_agent.txt.html). Эта система позволяет не вводить каждый раз пароль.

Но можно воспользоватся инструментом для автоматизации [expect](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect)

Comment: Адреса постоянно меняются, пароли приходят из вне. Мне нужно именно вписатт пароль.